# Jquery + When all previos fields (radio buttons,select and textbox) are filled then append a new box

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html output.

[image]

When user click on + (Add Tab) icon then how to check previos fields are filled or not 
If any fields is empty then a error message will come.

```
jQuery('.add-contact').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // check previous box is field or not

     {check code}

    var siteUrl = jQuery(this).data('url');
    var productId = jQuery(this).data('id');
    var id = jQuery(".nav-tabs").children().length; //think about it ;)
    var tabId = 'personalize_' + id;
    jQuery(this).closest('li').before('<li><a href="#personalize_' + id + '">Personalize</a> <span> x </span></li>');

    var DataPersionalize  = '<div class="tab-pane" id="' + tabId + '">';


    DataPersionalize += '</div>';

    // append data
    jQuery('.tab-content').append(DataPersionalize);


    jQuery('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(' + id + ') a').click();
});
```

How it is possible in case of radio button.

Thank

Comment: Seems like you need to add validation to your fields, have you used jQuery Validation? https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: @Esko ; i used validation like 
allGood=true;
$("input").each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() =="") {
                allGood=false;
                return false;
            }
        });
but i think it will not work for radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

You could create an if else statement with all of the items in the original conditional separated by &&  and check if each of your input fields has a value with a length > 0 and for the radio button do `$('.radio_button').is(':checked'))` If they all pass then you can open the tab. If they don't pass you can `$('.error-div').html("<div>Error Message</div>")`

Answer (score 0):

In case your radiobuttons all are in a group called `ring` and only one is selectable:

```
var isChecked = false,
    radios = document.getElementsByName("ring");
for(radio in radios) {
   isChecked = radios[radio].checked || isChecked;
}
console.log(isChecked);
```

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="ring1" name="ring">
<input type="radio" id="ring2" name="ring">
```

In case more than one are selectable, the same solution is usable, as long as you get the collection of required in the variable `radios`, lets say, id you use a class `rings`:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByClassName("rings");
```

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="ring1" class="rings">
<input type="radio" id="ring2" class="rings">
```